# Get the Last day of month in a string

Tags: c#

Hi I am able to get the first day of the month using this code:

```
static string FirstMonth = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

How do I get the last day of the month in the same date format?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime("2/4/15");

DateTime lastDayOfSameMonth = (new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Please, use [format code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) option while creating your answers. It will make the posts look much better. It is also a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, references to the documentation. That is not a requirement, but pleasantly looking posts with good formatting, explanations and references are far more likely to get upvotes and(or) be accepted.